# ASP.Net Firebase Messaging Web Push: how to know if a client actually received a push notification?

Tags: asp.net, firebase-cloud-messaging, web-push

I am trying to get Firebase WebPush notifcations running in my **ASP.Net web forms** application.
I can send messages and receive them in the browser via JavaScript (foreground and background is working).

The problem now is that Google reports that a message was sent successfully, although the client is not online. Through that, the message is lost. Short sequence to illustrate the problem:

```
1. Client browser connects to Firebase service and reports its registration token
2. User closes this browser (on PC) 
3. Wait 2 minutes
4. Firebase server sends WebPush notifcation to the previously received token
5. Google reports success 
6. Client never gets the notification
```

Does Firebase provide any functionality to report non-received messages?

I suspect it has to do with the *firebase-messaging-sw.js* file, but I can't (just) execute JS code on server-side. What is the proper way to deal with this?

Answer (score 0):

No, this is not part of Web Push standard.
You'll have make an additional http call from the service worker to your server to confirm the receipt.

Comment: So how does Google know when to retry sending a notification?
In their Developer Console, you can send Firebase test messages and specifiy a duration of the campaign. That implies that they need to know whether a client received a message or not.